# LInux: How does it handle content deletion from the middle of the file

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have two questions on how the read & deletion works in linux file system. I tried searching but couldn't get the right answers.

1) Random read to a position in the file: Consider the case of doing an lseek to a position followed by read from it. I am expecting that read will directly jump to the block containing this position. File system knows how many blocks are present in the file and the size of each block. It will know which block will go to through simple calculation. Is this correct?

2) Deleting content from the middle of the file: Let say a file is stored over 100 blocks. We delete the content from the second block. After this change, 2nd block is not completely filled. How is this change handled? Do we copy over the complete file by shifting the 3rd block upwards (and 4th to 3rd and so on) so that all the blocks are filled? This would be required so that random read is faster (as explained in 1st point).

Comment: There are some downvotes on the question. For deletion part, I did fair amount of research and I couldn't get any relevant answer.

Comment: This means that you need something higher-level than a file. Did you consider using libraries like [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdbm/) or [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) ? Or some database like [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/)? You probably should consider such tools!

Comment: Alos, very often, the data is cached in e.g. the file system or [page cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). And a file can also be memory mapped using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. The calculations are not necessarily simple; they depend on the filesystem and the size of the file.
2. And here's why you're getting downvotes, and why you couldn't find any relevant answers: **You *cannot* delete from the middle of a file.** You can only rewrite the file so that contents are closer to the beginning.

Comment: You could also *truncate* a file, that is delete its end.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding q.2 - the answer depends on the filesystem. In theory it is often possible to remove a fixed-length block from the middle of the file and then re-link the adjacent blocks. Yet practicality of such solution is very limited and so no popular filesystem seems to let you do this. Most filesystems expect that you "delete" the data from the middle of the file by rewriting the data (taking the data from the tail and writing them closer to the beginning of the file) and then truncating the tail.